# svg with dragable path stops working when one javascript phrase is moved inside the svg

Tags: javascript, svg, path, draggable

I am trying to have an svg with internal javascript, see here <"https://jsfiddle.net/melvinT/boaus7k1/76/">jsfiddle of svg draggable triangle path  it is three circles that drag a triangle.  But there is just a bit that stubbornly stop working when I move it into the svg, and I can not figure out why?
The section  that mysteriously stops moving when I drag it into the svg is the following (it is at the end) Why?  How can I move it into the svg?

```
var elements = [p1, p2, p3,];
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
elements[i].addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
}
```

Comment: The script **inside** your SVG tag has no meaning at all; you can place it **outside** the SVG, where most developers will expect it. I enhanced your JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannye/zfLdms3p/

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet discovered what the correct phrasing is.  SVG stand alone?  SVG stand alone complex?  SVG fragment.  It is a file that can be named .svg and opened.  For example [https://jsfiddle.net/melvinT/x2fLaopm/13/](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinT/x2fLaopm/13/)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman You can put a script element inside a SVG element just as you can put it in an HTML element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/script

Comment: Sure, but its execution does the same. That is why I said it has no (special) meaning

Comment: Note, putting script IN a SVG does have one advantage; it allows execution of script in Markdown files... Fun way of hacking Github Pages (generated from README.md) But that is past OPs skillset...

Comment: The name rang a bell.. https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you put the script element at the bottom of your SVG then it should work because then it will run after the circle elements have been loaded.

```html
<svg id="figure1" width="500" height="500">
  <style>
    #figure1 {
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
  </style>

  <path d="M170 150 20 110 250 60 z" stroke="pink" fill="none" id="controlPath"/>
  <circle cx="170" cy="150" r="8" id="p1"  fill="red"   style="cursor: move;"/>
  <circle cx="20" cy="110" r="8" id="p2" fill="black" style="cursor: move;"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="60" r="8" id="p3"  fill="lightgrey" style="cursor: move;"/>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[

var svg = document.getElementById('figure1');
svg.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
svg.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);

var controlPath = document.getElementById('controlPath');

var dragElem = null;
var p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
var p2 = document.getElementById('p2');
var p3 = document.getElementById('p3');

var elements = [p1, p2, p3,];
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
}

function onMouseMove(ev) {
  var p;

  if (!dragElem) {
    return;
  }

  p = getClientPointInSVG(ev);
  dragElem.setAttribute('cx', p.x - mouseOffsetX);
  dragElem.setAttribute('cy', p.y - mouseOffsetY);

  controlPath.setAttribute('d',
    'M' + p1.getAttribute('cx') + ' ' + p1.getAttribute('cy') +
    ' ' + p2.getAttribute('cx') + ' ' + p2.getAttribute('cy') +
    ' ' + p3.getAttribute('cx') + ' ' + p3.getAttribute('cy') +
    ' ' + 'z' );

}

function onMouseDown(ev) {
  var p;

  dragElem = ev.target;
  p = getClientPointInSVG(ev);
  mouseOffsetX = p.x - dragElem.getAttribute('cx');
  mouseOffsetY = p.y - dragElem.getAttribute('cy');
}

function getClientPointInSVG(ev) {
  var p, m;

  p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = ev.clientX;
  p.y = ev.clientY;

  m = dragElem.getScreenCTM();
  return p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());
}

function onMouseUp(ev) {
  dragElem = null;
}

var mouseOffsetX, mouseOffsetY;
    ]]>
   </script>
</svg>
```

Comment: it works! yay!   I had forgotten to put the header thing <svg id="figure1" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500" > and once that was done I could put it in an svg file and it open in a web browser.  Fabulous.  Thank you.  Still not sure what the correct name for this is?  SVG stand alone? SVG stand alone complex? SVG fragment? :>)